# How to use unnest function in data fusion

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

My input table is like this:

[image]

and I need output like this in data fusion (i.e if if qty=2 records need to repeated 2 times, if its 1 repeated once, if its n n times).

can you please any one help me in Cloud-datafusion what wrangler directive i can use to get the data in this format.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use next directives to create a list of needed size, then explode it and remove the field after:

- set-column :arr l=new('java.util.ArrayList');i=0;while(i lt qty) {l.add(i);i=i+1}; return l;
- flatten :arr
- drop :arr

Please note that the whole list of rows produced from a single row should fit into executor memory, so it's practical for smaller quantities (up to ~1000). To go bigger numbers, you would need to generate a dataset and use an advanced join.